# Openshift - rename route

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

How can I rename route that has been created via web console?
I go to `Applications>Routes`, selected route name, then `Action>Edit YAML` and I want to achieve the following change, from `test.site` into `old.test.site`

**Current route yml config**

```
...
metadata:
  name: test
  selfLink: /oapi/v1/namespaces/keycloak/routes/test
...
spec:
  host: test.site
...
status:
  ingress:
    - conditions:
        - lastTransitionTime: '2017-12-13T02:19:22Z'
          status: 'True'
          type: Admitted
      host: test.site
```

**Attempt**

```
...
metadata:
  name: test
  selfLink: /oapi/v1/namespaces/keycloak/routes/test
...
spec:
  host: old.test.site
...
status:
  ingress:
    - conditions:
        - lastTransitionTime: '2017-12-13T02:19:22Z'
          status: 'True'
          type: Admitted
      host: old.test.site
```

I get the following error messages:

> Failed to process the resource.
>   Reason: Route "test" is invalid: spec.host: Invalid value: "old.test.site": field is immutable

Comment: As far as I know you can't edit the host in place for an existing route. From the command line try ``oc get route test -o yaml > route.yaml``. Then edit the ``route.yaml`` and run ``oc replace route test -f route.yaml``. The ``replace`` action may allow you to do it. Else after editing local copy, try ``oc delete route test`` and ``oc apply route test -f route.yaml``. In doing this, when edit the file, you can delete the whole ``status`` section.

Answer (score 4):

As [Graham Dumpleton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128141/graham-dumpleton) wrote:

As far as I know you can't edit the host in place for an existing route. From the command line try

```
oc get route test -o yaml > route.yaml
```

Then edit the  `route.yaml`  and run

```
oc replace route test -f route.yaml
```

The  `replace`  action may allow you to do it. 
 Else after editing local copy, try

```
oc delete route test
```

and

```
oc apply route test -f route.yaml
```

In doing this, when edit the file, you can delete the whole  `status`  section.

But keep in mind there are exist some fields which are required and you cannot delete them.  That's why you had a problem with modification.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But what is the proper way of editing the host? I mean should replacing the value for `host` be just fine?

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw the `replace` command did not work (at least using OpenShift v4.8).
Instead I had to delete the route, then re-create it:

```
oc delete route test
oc process -f test-route.yaml namespace=$NAMESPACE domain=$DOMAIN | oc apply -f -
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to rename or delete the route, you can simply create a new one. You can have multiple routes for the same service, provided they have different names.

```
oc expose svc/yourservice --name=newroutename --hostname=newURL
```

Answer (score 0):

Once a route is given a Route Name, the Route Name becomes immutable.
You need to manually delete route & create a route again,

oc delete route test
oc apply route test -f route.yml

OR Go to Openshift Networking -> Routes section then delete the test route & create it again.